# I am getting these error:TypeError: avg_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python-3.x

```
def avg_1():

    print()

avg_1(['nancy',('math',70),('english',90),('science',90),('history',80)])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> ```
> avg_1(['nancy',('math',70),('english',90),('science',90),('history',80)])
> ```
>
> TypeError: avg_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because the definition of your function avg_1 does not  accept any argument, you must change it to "def avg_1(some_list_of_tuples)"

Answer (score 0):

`avg_1()` dont accept arguments.

but You call it with one argument

`['nancy',('math',70),('english',90),('science',90),('history',80)]`

to print your list You need one argument in `avg_1()`:

```
def avg_1(prt):

    print(prt)

avg_1(['nancy',('math',70),('english',90),('science',90),('history',80)])
```

now is `prt` in your function equals 
`['nancy',('math',70),('english',90),('science',90),('history',80)]` in function avg_1

than you can print this variable